# Drop down list's selected value resets on form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I go to edit a members Member Type by changing the drop down selected value, on postback the selected value resets itself to the top item and the user gets that member type.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

View -

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedMemberType, new SelectList(Model.MemberTypes, "ID", "Name", (int)Model.MemberType))
```

Model -

```
public class MemberDetailModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int SelectedMemberType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Member Type")]
    public int MemberType { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<MemberTypeModel> MemberTypes { get; set; }

    public MemberDetailModel()
    {
        MemberTypes = new List<MemberTypeModel>();
    }
}
```

Controller -

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        ViewBag.MemberType = new SelectList(_memberTypeService.GetAll(), "ID", "Name");

        MemberDetailModel member = _memberService.GetById(id);

        IEnumerable<Gender> genders = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))
                                                   .Cast<Gender>();

        return View(member);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(MemberDetailModel model)
    {
        model.MemberType = model.SelectedMemberType;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _memberService.UpdateMember(model);

            return View(member);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Why the use of `SelectedMemberType` and `MemberType`? I suspect it is this that is causing a problem. Try removing one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

As selectlist will be lost between postbacks, so just don't forget to set the `MemberTypes` again on postback. Most of the cases that is the issue.